# Ordenando array o vectores en c#

Tags: c#

Buenas,agradeceria si alguien me puede desmontar esto y explicarlo para "tontos". 
Entiendo cosas,por eso he llegado a ese punto del curso, pero no entiendo varias cosas.
Alguien con algun concepto claro ? Se que tengo que comparar los valores del vector, pero no entiendo como lo hace... Gracias !

```
public void Ordenar()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 4 - k; f++)
            {
                if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1])
                {
                    int aux;
                    aux = sueldos[f];
                    sueldos[f] = sueldos[f + 1];
                    sueldos[f + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Es sencillo... Favor de revisar [Ordenamiento de burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja), tu código es tal cuál al ejemplo del link.

Comment: Por que se pide el cierre de esta pregunta, este tipo de preguntas se han contestado en otras ocaciones por ejemplo -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/qu%C3%A9-es-lo-que-se-hace-en-este-bloque-while de las primera que aparecieron con una busqueda usando las palabras -> alguien me explica, pero existen muchas mas en difrentes tag que he leido con el tiempo.Saludos

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Bubble_sort_animation.gif

Comment: @AngelAngel Supongo que sea por el propósito o "filosofía" de StackOverflow. En principio esta comunidad está pensada para la resolución de problemas y no para la revisión y formación de algoritmos. Ese otro tipo de cuestiones igual encajan mejor en [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Intetare explicarlo como usted pide, *espero no cometer ningun error garrafal en el proceso por simplificar ect*

- lo que no veo es porque usarmos ese for con k,

ese for con k se encarga de itererar tantas veces como datos tenga el array lo confuso es que usa un **numero magico**<sup>1</sup> y no toma el tamaño del array con size lenght o cualquier cosa.

<sup>1</sup>**numero magico** me di cuenta despues de releer la respuesta pensando que quizas era confuso para usted,para esta caso en concreto:numero magico, me refiero a que poner o usar un numero que puede parecer puesto al azar en este caso el 4 que probablemente represente el tamaño del array, en lugar de usar algo mas expresivo como usar por ejemplo algo asi `mi_array.Lenght` o cualquier cosa, sea propiedad o metodo, o lo que sea que retorne un valor o del cual obtengas un valor.

- porque hace 2 recorridos, y luego en el for f, me encuentro con f<4-k.

En esta parte `if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1]){//..` toma los elemento y los compara, haciendo swap (intercambio) de las posiciones, si esto se cumple y asi con todos los elmenetos, en la primera iteracion de `for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)` porque `4-k` es 4. ahora al terminar la primera iteracion del for k ya tiene el mayor un puesto mas al final y haci hasta comparlos con todos osea los 4, pero el la siguiente iteracion "vuelta" ya tenemos el mayor en la posicion 4, de ahi a que se use `4-k` pues el ultimo ya es el mayor segun la condicion del if, pero el resto siguien estando sin ordenar (o no pero eso no lo sabemos) asi que los comprobamos y lo vamos desplazamos, pero ya sabemos que el 4 es el mas grande asi que paramos antes de llegar a su poscion, como se menciono de ahi `4-k` y asi hasta terminar con todos los datos.

- Tampoco entiendo ese [f+1] que le hace, si le asigna el otro puesto en el array o le aumenta el valor en 1. Creo que el valor que tenemos que mover, se almacena en la aux, pero no veo como la posicion 0 acaba siendo otra

---

```
if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1]){ //sueldo 0 > sueldo 0+1  sueldo = 1  para el siguiente parametro

      int aux;
      aux = sueldos[f]; // aux almcena el valor de sueldo en la posicion 0
      sueldos[f] = sueldos[f + 1]; //ahora a sueldo en la posicion 0 se le asigna la de sueldo f+1 como dijimos antes sueldo en la posicion 1 porque f = 0 para la primera iteracion 
      sueldos[f + 1] = aux; ahora en la variable aux tenemos el valor inicial de sueldo en la posicion 0 que es la de f para esa iteracion en se momento pues ahora mismo sueldo [0] tiene el valor de sueldo[f + 1], osea el mismo valor tanto para sueldo[0] como para sueldo[f + 1]y no pueden tener el mismo valor por ser movidos porque entonces nos estamos cargando un valor que estaba en sueldo[0] asi que tomamos el valor que "copiamos" al principio en aux y se lo asiganamos a sueldo[f + 1] intente imaginarselo mentalmente y vera como el dato avanza de posicion. Entonces al ser sueldo[0] diferente al valor inicial tenemos que volver a comprobarlo/comparalo en la siguiente iteracion de `for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)` pero solo hasta `4-k`.

}
```

se teminaria con el fok f y despues otra vez al for k hasta terminar el for k, pero en cada itretacion k vale un numero mas con lo que el for f solo itera hasta f < 4-k (donde k seria 0 luego 1 y asi) con lo que cada vez se deja sin "comprobar" mas valores de los que tenemos al final pues ya estan ordenado y eso lo determina 4-k

---

*para que se lea mejor*

---

`if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1]){` sueldo 0 > sueldo 0+1  sueldo = 1  para el siguiente parametro

---

`aux = sueldos[f];` aux almcena el valor de sueldo en la posicion 0

---

`sueldos[f] = sueldos[f + 1];` //ahora a sueldo en la posicion 0 se le asigna la de sueldo f+1 como dijimos antes sueldo en la posicion 1 porque f = 0 para la primera iteracion

---

`sueldos[f + 1] = aux;` ahora en la variable aux tenemos el valor inicial de sueldo en la posicion 0 que es la de f para esa iteracion en se momento pues ahora mismo `sueldo [0]` tiene el valor de `sueldo[f + 1]`, osea el mismo valor tanto para `sueldo[0]` como para `sueldo[f + 1]`y no pueden tener el mismo valor por ser movidos porque entonces nos estamos cargando un valor que estaba en `sueldo[0]` asi que tomamos el valor que "copiamos" al principio en `aux` y se lo asiganamos a `sueldo[f + 1]` **intente imaginarselo mentalmente y vera como el dato avanza de posicion**. Entonces al ser `sueldo[0]` diferente al valor inicial tenemos que volver a comprobarlo/comparalo en la siguiente iteracion de `for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)` pero solo hasta `4-k`.

---

```
public void Ordenar()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 4 - k; f++)
            {
                if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1])
                {
                    int aux;
                    aux = sueldos[f];
                    sueldos[f] = sueldos[f + 1];
                    sueldos[f + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Se esta dando formato pubicada no sea que se me borre la respuesta**

Comment: muchisimas gracias a todos, Angel por tu dedicado esmero :) , voy a releerlo mañana, ahora ya dormir. Espero entenderlo.
Resulta que son mas de 20 años sin tener la logica matematica, ni estudiar nada,me doy cuenta de si hubiera estudiado esto en aquella epoca seria mucho mas ligero todo :),
En fin muchas gracias , en cuanto lo tenga asimilado paso y lo comento !

Comment: @AgustinGimenezRojas no es complicado, no te preocupes en este caso por las matematicas, pues solo son sumas y restas, lo complicado es que si estas empezando puede ser un poco abstracto, y que quizas no tienes asimilado aun que cuando haces k++ por ejemplo el valor de esta variable aunmenta 1 es similar a hacer k = k +1 donde k es 0 u otro numero para 0, seria k = 0 + 1 - k ahora vale 1, despues  k ++ | k = k +1 | k = 1 + 1, k = 2, y haci mientras se esta ejecutando el ciclo for mientras se cumpla la condicion de k < 4 ahi se termina el for. suerte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void Ordenar(){ // metodo que ordena de menor a mayor un arreglo de unica y exclusivamente 5 elementos.
         for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){ //Hace un recorrido de 0 a 4 
             for (int f = 0; f < 4 - k; f++){ //en el primer intento quiere recorrer hasta cuatro luego hasta 3 y asi baja a 0
                 if (sueldos[f] > sueldos[f + 1]){//si el elemento en la posicion f el mayor al siguiente hace un intercambio
                    int aux;
                    aux = sueldos[f];//guarda el elemento en posicion f
                    sueldos[f] = sueldos[f + 1]; //pasa el elemento f+1 a la posicion f
                    sueldos[f + 1] = aux;// en la posicion f+1 pone el elemento que estaba en posicion f
                 } 
             }
         }
    }
```

TE pongo un recorrido del for...
[5,4,8,2,0]

k = 0,
f = 0,
f < 4-0? SI,
5>4? SI,
aux = 5,
sueldos[f] = 4,
sueldo[f+1] = 5,
[4,5,8,2,0]

k=0,
f=1,
f<4-0? SI,
5>8? NO,
[4,5,8,2,0]

k=0,
f=2,
f<4-0? SI,
8>2? SI,
aux = 8,
sueldos[f] = 2,
sueldo[f+1] = 8,
[4,5,2,8,0]

k = 0,
f = 3,
f < 4-0? SI,
8>0? SI,
aux = 8,
sueldos[f] = 0,
sueldos[f+1] = 8,
[4,5,2,0,8]
 con esto se supone que el ultimo elemento ya está ordenado, entonces para el siguiente recorrido solo va de 0 a 3 (4-k, k = 1).

Comment: lo que no veo es porque usarmos ese for con k, porque hace 2 recorridos, y luego en el for f, me encuentro con f<4-k . Tampoco entiendo ese [f+1] que le hace, si le asigna el otro puesto en el array o le aumenta el valor en 1. 
Creo que el valor que tenemos que mover, se almacena en la aux, pero no veo como la posicion 0 acaba siendo otra......